# Snake eating food (HTML5 canvas game)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

This is my first post so I hope that I put everything correctly down below here! :-P

I have a problem. Currently I'm making a snake game with a school friend of mine. We are making a snake game by using node.js so we can create a multiplayer snake game. Nothing really extreme just the basic snake game but then with more players.

Currently I've created a code that can move the snake and also will place food randomly on the canvas (I'm using the HTML5 Canvas element in which the game is played).

Now I'm stuck because I want to create a function that allows the snake to eat the food and then grow longer. As far as I know I have the function as it should be, but for some reason it does not work. My knowledge of javascript is very basic so what I'm doing here is all new for me. I will put the entire code down below so you can see it through.

I've created 2 javascript files. one that has the snake code in it and the other has the food code in it. The function that I'm referring about is inside the Snake script under Snake.prototype.move

I really hope that someone can help me out so I can proceed with our game.

This is the main code (Snake code):

```
    var game;

$(document).ready(function(){
    var canvas = $("#canvas")[0];
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var w = $("#canvas").width();
    var h = $("#canvas").height();
    var cw = 10;

    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, w, h);


    var GameObject = function() {
        this.snakes = [];
        this.foods = [];
    }

    game = new GameObject();

    var snake = new Snake(1, 15, 'testnaam'); 
    snake.create();
    game.snakes.push(snake);
    game.foods.push(new Food(w, cw));

    function loop() {
        window.setTimeout(loop, 60);    

        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);

        if(game.snakes.lenght !== 0) {
            for(i = 0; i < game.snakes.length; i++) {
                var s = game.snakes[i];
                s.paint(ctx, game);
            }
        } else {

        }

        if(game.foods.length !== 0) {
            for(var i = 0; i < game.foods.length; i++) {
                var f = game.foods[i];
                f.paint(ctx);
            }
        } else {

        }

    }

    loop();


    document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var key = e.which;
            if(key == "37" && snake.direction !="right") snake.direction = "left";
            else if(key == "38" && snake.direction !="down") snake.direction = "up";
            else if(key == "39" && snake.direction !="left") snake.direction = "right";
            else if(key == "40" && snake.direction !="up") snake.direction = "down";            

    }, false);


});

var Snake = function(player, length, alias){
    this.length = length;   
    this.pieces = [];       
    this.player = player;   
    this.position = {x: 0, y: 0}; 
    this.direction = "right";   
    this.color = this.color();
    this.getName = alias;

}


Snake.prototype.create = function(){ 
        for(var i = this.length -1; i >= 0; i--) {
        this.pieces.push({x: i, y: 0});
    }   
};
Snake.prototype.paint = function(ctx, game){

    this.move(game);
    for(var i = 0; i < this.pieces.length; i++){
            var c = this.pieces[i];

            ctx.fillStyle = this.color; 
            ctx.fillRect(c.x*10, c.y*10, 10, 10);   
        }
};

Snake.prototype.color = function(){ 
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
        color += letters[Math.round(Math.random() * 15)];
    }
    return color;
};

Snake.prototype.getName = function() {
    return this.alias;
}

Snake.prototype.getPosition = function() {
    return {x: this.x, y: this.y }
}

Snake.prototype.move =  function(game) { 
    var nx = this.pieces[0].x; 
    var ny = this.pieces[0].y;

    if(this.direction == "right")nx++; 
    else if(this.direction == "left")nx--;      
    else if(this.direction == "up")ny--;
    else if(this.direction == "down")ny++;


    if(Snake == game.foods[0].position.x && Snake == game.foods[0].position.y){ 
            console.log("raak");
            var tail = {
                x: nx,
                y: ny
            };
            Food.create();

    } else{
            var tail = this.pieces.pop();
            tail.x = nx; 
            tail.y = ny;
        }

    this.pieces.unshift(tail);  

};

Snake.prototype.collision = function(x, y, array){ 
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        if(array[i].x == x && array[i].y == y)
        return true;
    }   
    return false;
};
```

And This is the code for the food

```
    var Food = function(w, cw){
    this.w = w;
    this.cw = cw;
    this.position = this.create();
    console.log(this.position);
};

Food.prototype.create = function(){

    var min = 0;
    var max = (this.w/this.cw);

    return position = {
        x: Math.round(min + Math.random()* (Math.abs(min)+(max)))*this.cw, 
        y: Math.round(min + Math.random()* (Math.abs(min)+(max)))*this.cw
    } 
};

Food.prototype.paint = function(ctx){
    ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
    ctx.fillRect(this.position.x,this.position.y,10,10) 
};
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: You'll probably get more help if you reduce all this to just what you're having trouble with--the growth of the snake.

Comment: First look...you have a typo in loop():  game.snakes.lenght (length is misspelled).

Comment: I've adjusted the typo. Didn't change the problem but thanks for seeing that!

Comment: I would love to just paste a piece of the code in it but I wasn't sure if people need other parts of the code or something. So I just thought about putting the whole code in it ^^

Answer (score 1):

**[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/RG76t/)**

I had to fiddle with it a lot.. there is a lot of weirdness going on in the code, but this is the area I messed with primarily to get it working.

```
  Snake.prototype.move = function (game) {
       var nx = this.pieces[0].x;
       var ny = this.pieces[0].y;

       if (this.direction == "right") nx++;
       else if (this.direction == "left") nx--;
       else if (this.direction == "up") ny--;
       else if (this.direction == "down") ny++;

       /*
           * you werent testing the front pieces x and y, also since your multiplying the snake
           * pieces by 10, you need to divide the food positions by 10 for the coords to match up
       */
       if (this.pieces[0].x == game.foods[0].position.x / 10 && this.pieces[0].y == game.foods[0].position.y / 10) {
           console.log("raak");
           var tail = {
               x: nx,
               y: ny
           };
           // push your piece
           this.pieces.push(tail);
           // you have an array for prob to eventually have more than one on the screen.
           // for now i set food[0] to be a new piece of food. We dont have ref's to w and cw in this
           // func to I passed in the values.
           game.foods[0] = new Food(canvas.width, 10);

       } else {
           var tail = this.pieces.pop();
           tail.x = nx;
           tail.y = ny;
           // only unshift when we havent added a piece
           this.pieces.unshift(tail);
       }
   };
```

Basically you weren't testing the positions at all and you werent dividing the foods position by 10 when checking so the snake's position could never match the foods.